# Building MAUI project after Xamarin Forms migration results in 'Value cannot be null' error for .xaml files, how to solve it?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, maui

I have migrate my Xamarin Forms solution to MAUI with the upgrade-assistant but after the migration I have a problem with all .xaml files when I build the project I have that :

1>App.xaml : error : Value cannot be null.
1>App.xaml : error : Parameter name: key
...

Somebody can help me.

I have try 2 times to upgrade my solution and it's the same issue.

app.xaml code :

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="CheckMobile.App">


<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Warning">#FF8C00</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Error">#FF0000</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Agree">#008000</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Info">#3276b1</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Secondary">#EBEBEB</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DarkSecondary">#868e96</Color>

        <Style x:Key="searchFrame" TargetType="Frame">
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Fill" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,10,5,10" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,0" />
            <Setter Property="OutlineColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="searchNotMandatoryFrame" TargetType="Frame">
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Fill" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,10,5,10" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,0" />
            <Setter Property="OutlineColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="infoFrame" TargetType="Frame">
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Fill" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,10,5,10" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,0" />
            <Setter Property="OutlineColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnImage" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="40"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnSecondaryStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkSecondary}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkSecondary}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnAgreeStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Agree}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Agree}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnWarningStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnErrorStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Error}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Error}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="entryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="entryWarningStyle" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="editorStyle" TargetType="Editor">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblMicroStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="lblAgreeStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Agree}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblAgreeMicroStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Agree}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="lblWarningStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblWarningMicroStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblErrorStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Error}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblErrorMicroStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Error}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblDarkSecondaryStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkSecondary}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="lblDarkSecondaryMicroStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkSecondary}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblInfoStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblSmallInfoStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblInfoLargeStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblInfoErrorLargeStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Error}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblInfoSecondaryStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#000000" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblInfoMicroSecondaryStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#000000" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblInfoErrorMicroStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Error}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblInfoWarningMicroStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblWarningLargeStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lblLargeStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="searchStyle" TargetType="SearchBar">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="30" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
            <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Default" />
            <Setter Property="SeparatorColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lvNoHeightStyle" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
            <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Default" />
            <Setter Property="SeparatorColor" Value="{StaticResource Info}" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="lvPictureStyle" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FCFCFC" />
        </Style>


       </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Thanks a lot

Xamarin Fomrs to MAUI migration

Comment: How can I help, when I cannot see a single line of code?

Comment: I have add the code of my app.xaml but I have the same problem on all xaml more than 150.

Comment: which line is the FIRST line that gives this error?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve this one: <Setter Property="OutlineColor" Value="{StaticResource Warning}"/>

Answer (score 0):

You are using non-existent property names.

BorderRadius for Buttons.

If we open the button class, we see:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty;
```

This XAML you have will never work. You need to fix it.

Also, I recommend using Merged Dictionaries, and separate your styles in Styles XAML.

Edit: Now when I look closer, Frame does not have OutlineColor either...

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty;
```

It seems you will have to replace them in your project...
Make a test project, see if they look the same.